# A question on transfer modeling for the intervention analysis of time series data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, stationarity

When reading the section of intervention analysis of time series, I have one question regarding the following descriptions.

The following graph defines several response patterns for step function $S_t^T$ and pulse function $P_t^T$.

[image]

The step function and pulse function are defined as

[image]
[image]

With respect to the above patterns, the function of the form (13.1.4) in the following graph is claimed to be equivalent to the one (marked with yellow color in the following graph). Similarly, Equation (13.1.5) is claimed to be equivalent to the other one marked with yellow color. I do not know how to derive this equivalent relationship.

[image]