# ARIMAX model or ARDL?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, intervention-analysis, ardl

I would like to study the impact the advertising of a product on its sales (weekly data for 5 years).
As the final aim is to forecast what would be the impact on sales of a change in the advertising presence in the media, I was considering including also other variables (such as competitors prices, macroeconomics variables,…)
As I know that advertising has a long lasting effect and that, for example, at time t I would be only able to know prices at t-1 I need to include lags.
Would ARIMAX model be appropriate? 
Shall I just try to use a trend+seasonality+lagged variables?

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest using an ARIMA model with an intervention variable. The key of the analysis is the choice of the form of  
the intervention for the advertising campaign. See the first graph in [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83438/a-question-on-transfer-modeling-for-the-intervention-analysis-of-time-series-dat) for interventions with different shapes and durations. Flagging your question with `intervention-analysis` may result in more views and answers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess your suggestion is to model the advertising as an intervention variable...however what about competitor prices...etc...one of the possible utilization is to predict on different macroeconomics scenarios...should i also use these variables as regressors?

Comment: You can extend the model with other predictors as competitor prices and keep them in the model if they turn to be significant.